# python plotting from multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, multi-index

I am having trouble plotting the multi-index datafram below,
since I cant use the `m04hour.inde`x range value for some reason.

[output from m04hour.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW5Ro.png)

However, this plot command works fine:

```
m04hour['consumption (kWh)'].plot(figsize=(12,2))
```

But this one doesnt:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ax.plot(m04hour.index, m04hour['consumption(kWh)'],c='red',lw=1,label='queens')
```

Because the "`m04hour.index`" is returning the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

So the **question** is how to refer to the `m04hour.index` value for setting the plotting x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

You index in this m04hour is not pd.MultiIndex.  It is a index with tuples.
First let's convert that list of tuples into a pd.MultiIndex.

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ax.plot(m04hour.index.get_level_values(1), m04hour['consumption(kWh)'],c='red',lw=1,label='queens')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @GilesRichardson If this answer helped you, would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).  Thank you.